# MySQL Select multiple count in one query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

I have 2 tables - `departments` and `employees`. I want to select all columns from `departments` and also add a column with number of subdepartments and number of employees in each department.

Simplified tables look like this:

`departments`:

```
id      name            parent_id
---------------------------------
1       IT              NULL
2       HR              NULL
3       Bussiness       NULL
4       Web dev         1
5       Ecommerce       4
6       Advertisement   3
7       Control         3
8       Programmers     1
```

`employees`:

```
id      name            department_id
---------------------------------
1       Adam            1
2       Ben             8
3       Charles         7
4       David           4
5       Eugen           4
6       Frank           6
7       Gustav          6
8       Heremy          4
9       Igor            5
10      Jacob           3
```

Result I want is:

```
id      name            parent_id       department_count      employee_count
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       IT              NULL            2                     1
2       HR              NULL            0                     0
3       Bussiness       NULL            2                     1
4       Web dev         1               1                     3
5       Ecommerce       4               0                     1
6       Advertisement   3               0                     2
7       Control         3               0                     1
8       Programmers     1               0                     1
```

Here is my query, but it is not working properly. But if I remove 1 of the `COUNT`, the numbers are then correct. I think that the `NULL` values are the problem, but I don't know the solution.

```
SELECT d.*, COUNT(d2.parent_id) AS department_count, COUNT(e.id) AS employee_count
FROM department AS d
LEFT JOIN department AS d2 ON (d.id = d2.parent_id)
LEFT JOIN employees AS z ON (e.department_id = d.id)
GROUP BY d.id
ORDER BY d.id
```

Any improvement on my code is welcome.

Comment: I'm sorry, my mistake - it should have been 2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `d2.id` in your count function with distinct,so the repeated children for a department will be counted only once

```
SELECT d.*,
COUNT(distinct d2.id) AS department_count,
COUNT(distinct e.id) AS employee_count
FROM department AS d
LEFT JOIN department AS d2 ON (d.id = d2.parent_id)
LEFT JOIN employees AS e ON (e.department_id = d.id)
GROUP BY d.id
ORDER BY d.id
```

[`Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/527d7/6)

Answer (score 4):

You can try correlated queries as they provide straightforward logic:

```
SELECT d.*, 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM departments WHERE parent_id = d.id) as department_count,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employees WHERE department_id = d.id) as employees_count
FROM departments d
```

Comment: Correlated might be slow because they will be executed for each row  of departments table